# Chrome extension:Communicate between content script and webpage's script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in my content script which is calling a function in the webpage's javascript

```
var actualCode = '(' + function() {
 functionInMyWebPage();
}
+ ')();';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

This is working and it fires the `functionInMyWebPage()` function.

Now I need to get the returned value of this `functionInMyWebPage()` and call another function which defined in the content script itself. If I call it in the above script block it will complain as it has not defined.

Comment: Person who down-voted please explain the reason why! Your answer can be anything, but to down-vote  a question you need to have enough evidence prove that it's a stupid question!

Answer (score 1):

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page. It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse: JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any variables defined by content scripts.

More info [Content script execution environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment)